# "fn run" command giving error on MAC OS

Tags: fn

I'm getting this error while using 'fn run' command on Mac.

Error during build. Run with `--verbose` flag to see what went wrong. eg: `fn --verbose CMD`

Comment: And?  What does running it verbosely output?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Questions should contain what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you got. You are expected to do most of your own research first.